# Mysql join many tables in huge database

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

this is my first post here.
I need create a feed like facebook with many informations like users checkins, photos, badges, etc... i need a help to create just one query to do this. how can i do to create a join with this?

```
select reviews.id_user, reviews.id, reviews.review
from reviews
where reviews.id_user in (1,2,3,4,5)
order by reviews.created_time desc;

select placespops.id_user, placespops.id, placespops.id_pop
from placespops
where placespops.id_user in (1,2,3,4,5)
order by placespops.created_time desc;

select usersfoursquarecheckins.id_user, usersfoursquarecheckins.id
from usersfoursquarecheckins
where usersfoursquarecheckins.id_user in (1,2,3,4,5)
order by usersfoursquarecheckins.created_time desc;

select usersfacebookcheckins.id_user, usersfacebookcheckins.id
from usersfacebookcheckins
where usersfacebookcheckins.id_user in (1,2,3,4,5)
order by usersfacebookcheckins.created_time desc;

select placesphotos.id_user, placesphotos.id
from placesphotos
where placesphotos.id_user in (1,2,3,4,5)
order by placesphotos.created_time desc;

select usersbadges.id_user, usersbadges.id
from usersbadges
where usersbadges.id_user in (1,2,3,4,5)
order by usersbadges.created_time desc;
```

The question is, how join all in one query?

Comment: Are you looking to get each type, ordered by created_time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it looks as though the simplest way to do this would be to union the result sets - like so:

```
select reviews.id_user, 
       reviews.created_time, 
       reviews.id review_id, 
       reviews.review, 
       null placespop_id, 
       null id_pop,
       null usersfoursquarecheckin_id,
       null usersfacebookcheckins_id,
       null placesphotos_id,
       null usersbadges_id
from reviews
where reviews.id_user in (1,2,3,4,5)
union all
select placespops.id_user, 
       placespops.created_time, 
       null review_id, 
       null review, 
       placespops.id placespop_id, 
       placespops.id_pop,
       null usersfoursquarecheckin_id,
       null usersfacebookcheckins_id,
       null placesphotos_id,
       null usersbadges_id
from placespops
where placespops.id_user in (1,2,3,4,5)
union all
select usersfoursquarecheckins.id_user, 
       usersfoursquarecheckins.created_time, 
       null review_id, 
       null review, 
       null placespop_id, 
       null id_pop, 
       usersfoursquarecheckins.id usersfoursquarecheckin_id,
       null usersfacebookcheckins_id,
       null placesphotos_id,
       null usersbadges_id
from usersfoursquarecheckins
where usersfoursquarecheckins.id_user in (1,2,3,4,5)
union all
select usersfacebookcheckins.id_user, 
       usersfacebookcheckins.created_time,
       null review_id, 
       null review, 
       null placespop_id, 
       null id_pop, 
       null usersfoursquarecheckin_id,
       usersfacebookcheckins.id usersfacebookcheckins_id,
       null placesphotos_id,
       null usersbadges_id
from usersfacebookcheckins
where usersfacebookcheckins.id_user in (1,2,3,4,5)
union all
select placesphotos.id_user, 
       placesphotos.created_time,
       null review_id, 
       null review, 
       null placespop_id, 
       null id_pop, 
       null usersfoursquarecheckin_id,
       null usersfacebookcheckins_id,
       placesphotos.id placesphotos_id,
       null usersbadges_id
from placesphotos
where placesphotos.id_user in (1,2,3,4,5)
union all
select usersbadges.id_user,
       usersbadges.created_time,
       null review_id, 
       null review, 
       null placespop_id, 
       null id_pop, 
       null usersfoursquarecheckin_id,
       null usersfacebookcheckins_id,
       null placesphotos_id,
       usersbadges.id usersbadges_id
from usersbadges
where usersbadges.id_user in (1,2,3,4,5)
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, but return index out of range.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you change `order by 2 desc` to be `order by created_time desc`?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
    SELECT r.id_user rid_user, r.id rid, r.review
          , p.id pid, p.id_pop
          , ufsq.id_user ufsqid_user, ufsq.id ufsqid
          , ufbk.id_user ufbkid_user, ufbk.id ufbkik
          , pp.id_user ppid_user, pp.id ppid
          , ub.id_user ubid_user, ub.id ubid
       FROM reviews r
 INNER JOIN placespops p ON r.id_user = p.id_user
 INNER JOIN usersfoursquarecheckins ufsq ON r.id_user = ufsq.id_user
 INNER JOIN usersfacebookcheckins ufbk ON r.id_user = ufbk.id_user
 INNER JOIN placesphotos pp ON r.id_user = pp.id_user
 INNER JOIN usersbadges ub ON r.id_user = ub.id_user

      WHERE r.id_user IN (1,2,3,4,5)
   ORDER BY reviews.created_time desc;
```

This is much more efficient and easier to manage than a huge `UNION`

Comment: Hi Richard, this is more elegant but return many duplicate rows... you know how to fix this?

Comment: It's unlikely to be more efficient, though it may well be easier to manage. However, a bigger problem is that there may well be multiple entries in each table for each `id_user` - so you will get m*n*p*q*r*s rows returned for each user, instead of m+n+p+q+r+s rows.

Comment: As written, it will also ignore users that aren't in the reviews table.

Comment: Yes, if rows are fully duplicate, you can add `DISTINCT` right after `SELECT`, but this is not very efficient and you'll probably want to replace the `LEFT JOIN`s by `INNER JOIN`s

Comment: @Mark, a `LEFT JOIN` will not depend on users being in any of the tables. Only a `RIGHT` or `INNER` join will ignore those. This is the only correct way to go about this query, a `UNION` is used to 'connect' similar tables that have the same fields. In your example you 'fake' all the fields that don't exist in that table, thus 'creating' those fields for all tables with a `null` value..

Comment: @Richard: A left join *from* the reviews table to other tables will return all rows that are in the reviews table and none that aren't in it. Changing all the left joins to inner joins will exclude all users that are missing from *any* of the tables - you will still get m*n*p*q*r*s rows for each user returned.

Comment: Yes, the results can be filtered by using either `DISTINCT` or using `GROUP BY`

Comment: No, neither distinct nor group by will help in this case. As a simple example, consider a user with two reviews (on 1/1/12 and 2/1/12) and three facebook checkins (on 1/2/12, 2/2/12 and 3/2/12) - using the join method you will get six records returned (one for 1/1/12 and 1/2/12, one for 2/1/12 and 1/2/12, and so on). Using distinct or group by will still return six records, because you have six different combinations of the records in question. Now apply this to more realistic levels of data - where each user may have hundreds of entries in each table - and do the maths.